# Multiple selecting and deleting in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog

I have so many files to delete, to do that I am using ArcCatalog but I can do only one by one.

Is there any way to delete many files at the same time. Also, I would like to know how to select more than files in ArcCatalog as well.

Answer (score 12):

You just need to make sure that you are in the Contents view - then you can use the Shift and Ctrl keys to multiple select.

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that changing to Contents View cannot be done on Geodatabases currently set as Default